# Subtracting Dates in Unix

Tags: date, unix, ksh

is there a way to subtract a month from a date or at least 30 days in unix.

example:

[yyy-mm-dd] - 30 days

2011-07-23 - 30 days

By the way, the date can be any date depending on the user input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For an arbitrary date,

```
$ date -d "2011-07-23 - 1 month" "+%F"
2011-06-23
$ date -d "2011-07-23 - 30 days" "+%F"
2011-06-23
$ date -d "2011-08-23 - 1 month" "+%F"
2011-07-23
$ date -d "2011-08-23 - 30 days" "+%F"
2011-07-24
```

This is GNU date

---

Without GNU date, you can fall back to perl. The Time::Piece and Time::Seconds module *should* be available in perl 5.12

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -e '
    print "date\t-1 month\t-30 days\n";
    while (@ARGV) {
        my $t = Time::Piece->strptime(shift, "%Y-%m-%d");
        print $t->ymd, "\t";
        print $t->add_months(-1)->ymd, "\t";
        $t -= 30*ONE_DAY; 
        print $t->ymd, "\n";
    }
' 2011-07-23 2011-08-23
```

```
date    -1 month    -30 days
2011-07-23  2011-06-23  2011-06-23
2011-08-23  2011-07-23  2011-07-24
```

Comment: date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]

Comment: What's your OS? What version of perl do you have?

Comment: My OS is AIX and the version of my perl is perl 5, version 12

Answer (score 4):

There is no both straightforward and portable way, all other replies so far are using Gnu specific extensions.

This should work on any Unix:

```
date "+%Y %-m %-d" |
(
  read y m d
  m=$(($m - 1))
  [ $m = 0 ] && { m=12; y=$(($y - 1)); }
  [ $d = 31 -a \( $m = 4 -o $m = 6 -o $m = 9 -o $m = 11 \) ] && d=30
  [ $d -gt 28 -a $m = 2 ] && d=28
  printf "%04d:%02d:%02d\n" $y $m $d
)
```

Comment: This is very good. For me however there are numerous ways the GNU core utilities are better, I've taken the decision to just install GNU utils anywhere I am doing work.

Comment: @merlin Indeed. There are still rare cases where the GNU toolkit isn't installed and installing it isn't an option.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

**`date -d "30 days ago" "+%Y%m%d00"`**

Answer (score 0):

```
#Current Date
 date +'%Y:%m:%d'
 2013:10:04

#Date a month ago
 date --date='-1 month' +'%Y:%m:%d. Last month was %B.'
 2013:09:04. Last month was September.
#%B prints out locale's full month name.
```

Type **"info coreutils date invocation"** in terminal and learn more.
Section: 28.7 Relative items in date strings. **File:** coreutils.info

EDIT: Looks OP wants to have the user input of date.

```
#Nov 1 2012 can be  modified to suit user's input. 
 date --date="$(date -d "Nov 1 2012")-1 month" +'%Y:%m:%d'
 2012:10:01
```